# Existence of a particular matrix $A$ $\in \mathrm{SO}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: isometry, orthogonal-matrices

I need to prove that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ exists a matrix $A$ $\in \mathrm{SO}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (orthogonal matrixes with determinant equal to 1) such that the inputs of the first row are equal to $1/\sqrt{n}$.

For example, for $n = 2$ we have that A must be:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 
a & b 
\end{pmatrix}$$

If $A$ has to be orthogonal it has to verify $AA^T = Id$ which gives the following equation system:

$$\left.\begin{matrix}
a^2 + b^2 = 1\\ 
\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{2}} = 0
\end{matrix}\right\} \Rightarrow 
\left.\begin{matrix}
a = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 
b = \mp \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{matrix}\right\}\overset{det(A)=1}{\Rightarrow }\left.\begin{matrix}
a = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 
b = + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{matrix}\right\}$$

The problem is that I don't know how to do it for an arbitrary $n$. I tried to write the equations similarly to the example but that wasn't successful.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by **Gram–Schmidt process** you can always create an orthonormal basis starting from a basis that contains  the given vector $v_1=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},...)$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

putting the vectors of the basis in a matrix (as rows or columns) you obtain an orthogonal matrix

Comment: Very minor point:  this may not lead to a *special* orthogonal matrix, though.  It's easy to fix this if it happens: just swap any two rows or any two columns.